# How to groupBy an Array of Objects and convert the duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures

Hello to all i have this data structure that i need to group and if there are any duplicates to convert those two objects it in one line..

**Data Structure**

```
var shipTo = [
  { addressLine1: "address 1", name: "Jeff" },
  { addressLine1: "address 2", name: "Taylor" },
  { addressLine1: "address 1", name: "Megan" },
  { addressLine1: "address 3", name: "Madison" },
];
```

**Grouped function**

```
function groupArrayOfObjects(list, key) {
  return list.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
}
```

I have groupedBy address attrube by this function above by address

```
const groupedAddress = groupArrayOfObjects(shipTo, "addressLine1");
```

My new data-structure is

[image]

My final Result wanna be like this :

`Shipping Address for Shipment 1 & 3 is "address 1"`

`Shipping Address for Shipment 2 is "address 2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` can take the index of the current array element as the 3rd parameter. you can then pass it to your accumulator and in the final array can do what you want with it

```js
var shipTo = [
  { addressLine1: "address 1", name: "Jeff" },
  { addressLine1: "address 2", name: "Taylor" },
  { addressLine1: "address 1", name: "Megan" },
  { addressLine1: "address 3", name: "Madison" },
];

function groupArrayOfObjects(list, key) {
  return list.reduce(function (rv, x, idx) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push({...x, index:idx+1});
    return rv;
  }, {});
}

const groupedAddress = groupArrayOfObjects(shipTo, "addressLine1");
console.log(groupedAddress)


//for completeness
Object.values(groupedAddress).forEach((address) => {
    let addressName = address[0].addressLine1
  let joinedIndices = address.map(({index}) => index).join(" & ")
  console.log(`Shipping Address for Shipment ${joinedIndices} is "${addressName}"`)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer was "to the point" 100% !!!
perfect response at 10mins or so :)